# How to construct a tensor product of two preadditive categories in pure categorical fashion?

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, abelian-categories, universal-property

Let $\mathsf C$ and $\mathsf D$ be two preadditive categories (by an preadditive category I mean a category together with compatible abelian group structure on every hom-set).

I thought of constructing a "tensor product" $\mathsf C\otimes\mathsf D$ such that $\text{ob}(\mathsf C\otimes\mathsf D)=\text{ob}(\mathsf C\times\mathsf D)$ and $\hom_{\mathsf C\otimes\mathsf D}((M,M'),(N,N'))=\hom_{\mathsf C}(M,N)\otimes\hom_{\mathsf D}(M',N')$. And I also thought of proving a universal property of $\mathsf C\otimes\mathsf D$: there exists a "bilinear" functor from $\mathsf C\times\mathsf D$ to $\mathsf C\otimes\mathsf D$ satisfying that every "bilinear" functor from $\mathsf C\times\mathsf D$ to another additive category can be factored through uniquely.

I think the above idea is very natural and I tried to acheive it using only the universal property of tensor product in $\mathsf{Ab}$. But all the proofs I ever found relies on the construction of tensor product of abelian groups. Does anyone know a pure category-theoretical construction and proof? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't the Deligne box product the one that is generally used?

Comment: A word on terminology: you're really talking about "categories enriched in abelian groups", or "preadditive categories". The term "additive category" is usually reserved for a preadditive category which in addition has all finite direct sums. If you require existence of direct sums in the definition of an additive category, then it's not clear that the tensor of additive categories is additive.

Comment: @tcamps I've corrected it. Thanks for your reminder, and thanks for your excellent answer.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially what you want is stated in Kelly's [Basic Concepts Of Enriched Category Theory](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10.pdf#page=18). The tensor product $\mathcal{C} \otimes \mathcal{D}$ of categories enriched in a symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{V}$ can be defined in the obvious way. As Kelly discusses (starting in the last paragraph of page 12 and going into page 13), a functor $\mathcal{C} \otimes \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{E}$ is given by a function $T: \mathsf{Ob}\mathcal{C} \times \mathsf{Ob}\mathcal{D} \to \mathsf{Ob}\mathcal{E}$, and, for each $c \in \mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{V}$-functors $T(c,-): \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{E}$ and for each $d \in \mathcal{D}$, $\mathcal{V}$-functors $T(-,d): \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{E}$ which agree with $T$ on objects and satisfy a compatibility condition (Kelly's diagram 1.21). As Kelly says, the verification is routine.

Now let $\mathcal{V}= \mathsf{Ab}$ be the cosmos of abelian groups. A functor of ordinary categories $T: \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{E}$ is bilinear if and only if the functors $T(c,-)$ and $T(-,d)$ are linear, and the compatibility condition arising from the ordinary functor $T$ being a functor is equivalent to the compatibility condition for the enriched functor. So a bilinear functor gives rise to an enriched functor and conversely.